# LIBGDX - Table's textButtons are not filling the respective rows

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I was recently working on a game which utilises Scene2D until I ran into this problem as shown in this picture:

[image]

The bounds in which I'm able to click the button exceed the actual TextButton's area

I've read the documentation for TableLayouts in the GitHub page [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table) and have read different articles about Scene2D in general, and I tried fiddling around with the different functions (eg padding, colSpan) to try to come to a solution but I can't seem to find a work around for this.

**Here is the code responsible for the setup and drawing of the table:**

```java
table = new Table();
table.setDebug(true);
table.add(graphicsButton).width(200f).height(200f);
table.row();
table.add(audioButton).width(200f).height(200f);
table.row();
table.add(backToTitleButton).width(200f).height(200f);

table.setBounds(0, 0, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());

stage.addActor(table);
```

**And here is the rest of the code** (note that I haven't centred the text within the buttons yet, I've only added filler values, also - I've removed the empty functions from the Screen class for convenience)

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
import com.thesameritan.game.GUI.UI;

public class OptionsScreen extends ScreenProperties implements Screen {

    private Stage stage;
    private Table table;

    OptionsScreen (final Game game) {
        super();

        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        TextButton backToTitleButton = UI.createNewButton("BACK", buttonStyle, 0.8f, 25f, 0.9f); //creates button from another class with text, style, padBottom, padLeft and fontScale
        TextButton graphicsButton = UI.createNewButton("GRAPHICS", buttonStyle, 0.9f, 20f, 0.9f);
        TextButton audioButton = UI.createNewButton("AUDIO", buttonStyle, 0.9f, 20f, 0.9f);


        backToTitleButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                //branch to title
            }
        });

        graphicsButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                //branch to graphics
            }
        });

        audioButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                //branch to options
            }
        });

        table = new Table();
        table.setDebug(true);
        table.add(graphicsButton).width(200f).height(200f);
        table.row();
        table.add(audioButton).width(200f).height(200f);
        table.row();
        table.add(backToTitleButton).width(200f).height(200f);

        table.setBounds(0, 0, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());

        stage.addActor(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void render (float delta) {
        clearScreen(); //from ScreenProperties
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        disposeObjects(); //from ScreenProperties
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

What I would like is either *minimising the gaps between the buttons without affecting the button's size* - which again, I've tried by changing the `.width()` and `.height()` values or *actually reduce the size of the interactive area (shown in the red lines)*

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting and missing part here is UI.createNewButton.

Instead of setting debug to the outer table, you can debug the button itself: `backToTitleButton.setDebug(true)`. You'll see that the click bounds doesn't exceed the buttons area, but the graphical representation is not correct. I suspect you aren't using a Ninepatch for the Rectangle.